# Why this button works in IE but not in Firefox?

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc-3, internet-explorer, firefox, button

I have strange issue and I don't know how to fix. This button works perfectly in IE , but not in Firefox.
This is the HTML code:

```
<div class="divbutonSave" onclick="Save()" style="float: right;">
<span>Save</span>
</div>
```

And this is the Javascript code:

```
 function Save() {
var poz = '1';
var rowCount = dataTable.rows.length;
var ala0 = "";
for (var i = 1; i < rowCount; i++) {
var c = document.getElementById("chk " + i);
if (c.checked == 1)
ala0 += dataTable.rows[i].cells[1].innerText + "^";
var ala = ala0.substring(0, ala0.length - 1);
}
$.ajax({
url: '/ProjectAdministrator/ProjectAdministratorProject/Partners',
data: { pozActivity: poz, listapart: ala },
dataType: "Json",
type: "POST",
error: function () {
alert("Error");
},
success: function (data) {
window.close();
}
});
}
```

Any suggestions? Thanks in advance

Comment: Can you elaborate what part is broken? Any console error messages?

Comment: Well, onclick events work in chrome, ie, ff, opera etc so the error lies in your javascript. As we cannot test your ajax. If you could upload your page and give link or something. Press F12 check error console. Also google up JQuery AJAX error messeages and how to output them. This will help you.

Comment: Element referenced by ID/NAME in the global scope. Use W3C standard document.getElementById() instead.
 

var rowCount = dataTable.rows.length;

GFPart...itate=1 (line 14)

TypeError: c is null
[Break On This Error]  

if (c.checked == 1)

Answer (score 2):

I'd suggest if you want a button, you should use a `button` in your markup, rather than a `div`. That way your markup will represent what it means, and it may have the side effect of working properly too.